# How can I resolve undefined variable and trying to get property of non-object in errors?

Tags: php, wordpress

When my test site has debugging set to false, all is well. When I go to debug my templates, I'm seeing the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: post in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/functions.php on line 15

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/functions.php on line 15
```

Here is my code but I can't tell what the variable is or the property of the non-object.

```
function excerpt($num) {
 $limit = $num+1;
 $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
 array_pop($excerpt);
 $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)."... (<a href='" .get_permalink($post->ID) ." '>Read more</a>)";
 echo $excerpt;
}
```

This is the loop I'm using in my template:

```
<?php $postslist = get_posts('category=4&numberposts=3&order=DESC&orderby=post_date');
foreach ($postslist as $post) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class="post_item">
<span class='side_date'><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><br />
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php excerpt(11); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?></div>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Where do you define `$post`?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean? but this is the loop I'm using in my template

`<?php $postslist = get_posts('category=4&numberposts=3&order=DESC&orderby=post_date');
foreach ($postslist as $post) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class="post_item">
<span class='side_date'><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><br />
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php excerpt(11); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?></div>`

Comment: Your code is using `get_permalink($post->ID)`, but you've not defined `$post` anywhere. That's why you're getting a notice about an undefined variable. (And it's a lot easier to read code if you edit it into your question)

Comment: Sorry about the code displaying poorly. I've added it to my question. So where/how would I define the post. Do you have an example? I've looked at the codex and googled it, but just not sure...

Comment: I think all you need to do is change your loop so you're calling `excerpt(11, $post);`, and your function definition to `function excerpt($num, $post) {`

Comment: That's it!! 
Thanks so much Andrew. So I understand more clearly, my function was telling the loop what to do but was not specific enough about "what" it's doing it to?

I'd give you points or check that you solved this but you answered as a question... Let me know if I can credit you for this and THANKS so much!

Comment: No problem - I'm happy to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
global $post;
```

to the top of your function.